# Poorva PEETIKE Vishnu Devotional Song

Tags: vishnu, vishnu-sahasranama

I am searching the translitterated text of the “ POORVA PEETIKE “ .
As far i understood should be the first part of the Vishnu SAHASRANAMA, but the words of POORVA PEETIKE are different from the classical Sahasranama.

Anyone have a link about it?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Poorva Peetika"](https://stotranidhi.com/hi/sri-vishnu-sahasranama-stotram-poorvapeetika-in-hindi/) of Vishnu Sahasranamam is the First Part and discussion between Bhishma and Yudhistara in **MahaBharat**. Yudhistara(Dharma Raja) asks various questions to Bhishma. Bhishma reply and clarifies all questions asked by Yudhishtara.